# This is how I installed JRuby on Windows -> Why did it not work?

Tags: windows, installation, jruby

```
* Download JRuby 1.20. (zip file)
* Extract the zip into C:\JRuby120
* Edit sytem "environment variables":
* Add JRUBY_HOME -> point it to C:\JRuby120
* Modify the PATH environment variable to point to C:\JRuby120\bin;
```

After all this, I open up cmd.exe and type **jruby**

->"The system cannot find the path specified"

What did I do wrong?

I removed echo_off from C:\JRuby120\bin\jruby.bat, C:\JRuby120\bin_jrubyvars.bat and C:\JRuby120\bin_jrubyvmopts.bat and invoked jruby from cmd.exe. This was the output:

```
C:\>rem --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

C:\>rem jruby.bat - Start Script for the JRuby Interpreter 

C:\>rem

C:\>rem for info on environment variables, see internal batch script _jrubyvars.bat 

C:\>setlocal

C:\>rem Sometimes, when jruby.bat is being invoked from another BAT file, 

C:\>rem C:\JRuby120\bin\ is incorrect and points to the current dir, not to JRuby's bin dir, 

C:\>rem so we look on the PATH in such cases. 

C:\>IF EXIST "C:\JRuby120\bin\_jrubyvars.bat" (set FULL_PATH=C:\JRuby120\bin\ )  ELSE (set FULL_PATH=C:\JRuby120\bin\ ) 

C:\>call "C:\JRuby120\bin\_jrubyvars.bat"  

C:\>rem Environment Variable Prequisites: 

C:\>rem

C:\>rem   JRUBY_OPTS    (Optional) Default JRuby command line args. 

C:\>rem

C:\>rem   JAVA_HOME     Must point at your Java Development Kit installation. 

C:\>rem

C:\>rem ----- Save Environment Variables That May Change -------------------------- 

C:\>set _CLASSPATH=.; 

C:\>set _CP= 

C:\>set _JRUBY_CP= 

C:\>set JRUBY_BAT_ERROR=0 

C:\>rem ----- Verify and Set Required Environment Variables ----------------------- 

C:\>if not "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin" == "" goto gotJava 

C:\>set JRUBY_HOME=C:\JRuby120\bin\.. 

C:\>rem ----- Prepare Appropriate Java Execution Commands ------------------------- 

C:\>if not "" == "" goto gotCommand 

C:\>set _JAVA_COMMAND= 

C:\>set JAVA_COMMAND=java 

C:\>if not "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" goto noTitle 

C:\>rem set _STARTJAVA=start "JRuby" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin\bin\java" 

C:\>set _STARTJAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin\bin\java 

C:\>goto gotTitle 

C:\>rem ----- Set up the VM options 

C:\>call "C:\JRuby120\bin\_jrubyvmopts"  

C:\>set _MEM=-Xmx500m 

C:\>if not defined JAVA_MEM goto memOptDone 

C:\>set _STK=-Xss1024k 

C:\>if not defined JAVA_STACK goto stackOptDone 

C:\>set _VM_OPTS= 

C:\>set _RUBY_OPTS= 

C:\>set _DFLT_VM_OPTS= 

C:\>set _JAVA_VM=-client 

C:\>set SAFE_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin 

C:\>set SAFE_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin 

C:\>rem

C:\>rem Can you believe I'm rewriting batch arg processing in batch files because batch 

C:\>rem file arg processing sucks so bad? Can you believe this is even possible? 

C:\>rem http://support.microsoft.com/kb/71247 

C:\>rem Escape any quotes. Use _S for ', _D for ", and _U to escape _ itself. 

C:\>rem We have to escape _ itself, otherwise file names with _S and _D 

C:\>rem will be converted to to wrong ones, when we un-escape. See JRUBY-2821. 

C:\>set _ARGS= 

C:\>if not defined _ARGS goto vmoptsDone 

C:\>set _VM_OPTS= -client -Xmx500m -Xss1024k  

C:\>set _DFLT_VM_OPTS= 

C:\>set _MEM= 

C:\>set _STK= 

C:\>set _ARGS= 

C:\>set _VAL= 

C:\>set _CMP= 

C:\>set _CMP1= 

C:\>set _JAVA_VM= 

C:\>set _RUNJAVA="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin\bin\java" 

C:\>rem ----- Set Up The Boot Classpath ---------------------------------------- 

C:\>for %i in ("C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\jruby*.jar") do @call :setjrubycp %i 

C:\>if not "" == "" goto addjrubycp 

C:\>set JRUBY_CP=C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\jruby.jar 

C:\>goto :EOF 

C:\>for %i in ("C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\bsf*.jar") do @call :setjrubycp %i 

C:\>if not "C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\jruby.jar" == "" goto addjrubycp 

C:\>set JRUBY_CP=C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\jruby.jar;C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\bsf.jar 

C:\>goto :EOF 

C:\>rem ----- Set Up The System Classpath ---------------------------------------- 

C:\>for %i in ("C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\*.jar") do @call :setcp %i 

C:\>if not "" == "" goto add 

C:\>set CP=C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\bsf.jar 

C:\>goto :EOF 

C:\>if not "C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\bsf.jar" == "" goto add 

C:\>set CP=C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\bsf.jar;C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\jruby.jar 

C:\>goto :EOF 

C:\>if not "C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\bsf.jar;C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\jruby.jar" == "" goto add 

C:\>set CP=C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\bsf.jar;C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\jruby.jar;C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\profile.jar 

C:\>goto :EOF 

C:\>goto :EOF 

C:\>if 0 == 0 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin\bin\java"  -client -Xmx500m -Xss1024k  -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\jruby.jar;C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\bsf.jar" -classpath "C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\bsf.jar;C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\jruby.jar;C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib\profile.jar;.;" -Djruby.home="C:\JRuby120\bin\.." -Djruby.lib="C:\JRuby120\bin\..\lib" -Djruby.shell="cmd.exe" -Djruby.script=jruby.bat org.jruby.Main   

C:\>set E=3 

C:\>call "C:\JRuby120\bin\_jrubycleanup"
```

Comment: Now that you've got it working, go back and put those "@echo off" lines back in.  You don't want to see all that crap every time you run jruby.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, that's what you're supposed to do.  Go to the command line and enter `echo %PATH%` and make sure your jruby bin directory is on there.

---

### EDIT:

Ignore the above, that's not the error you'd get for jruby not being in the path.  The "The system cannot find the path specified" error is because a path doesn't exist, most likely it's the path to your Java JDK.  Run `echo %JAVA_HOME%`.  Make sure that path is correct.  If you don't have the Java JDK, you can [download it here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp).

---

### EDIT 2:

Having seen the output of jruby.bat, the problem appears to either be in finding `_jrubyvars.bat`, or finding something called within it.  The only thing it calls is `_jrubyvmopts.bat`, which doesn't call anything else.  Make sure that `C:\JRuby120\bin\_jrubyvars.bat` and `C:\JRuby120\bin\_jrubyvmopts.bat` exist, although I can't see a reason why they shouldn't.  If they both exist, then the next step would be to remove the `@echo off` lines from each of them and see if we can find exactly where the bad call is taking place.

---

### EDIT 3:

Having seen all that output, it looks like `JAVA_HOME` is set to "`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin\`"  `JAVA_HOME` should be the parent directory: 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\`".  Give that a try and cross your fingers this time.

Comment: I also have Ruby (MRI) installed. Would that cause a conflict?

Comment: Thanks for following up. JAVA_HOME is pointing to my JRE. Does it need to point to the JDK specifically?

Comment: My JAVA_HOME is pointing to my JDK now instead of the JRE that it was pointing to before. But I get the same error: "The system cannot find the path specified." when I type jruby at the command prompt.

Comment: Edit the C:\jruby120\bin\jruby.bat file and remove the `@echo off` line at the top.  Then run jruby and add the output to your question so we can get a better idea what is going wrong.

Comment: I added the output but I'm not sure what it means. Does it mean it can't find this path: "C:\JRuby120\bin\_jrubyvars.bat"

Comment: Thanks again. 

I removed echo_off from C:\JRuby120\bin\jruby.bat, C:\JRuby120\bin_jrubyvars.bat and C:\JRuby120\bin_jrubyvmopts.bat and invoked jruby from cmd.exe. The output is above. I can't make head nor tail of it. I tried modifying my CLASSPATH to see if that made any difference. My CLASSPATH now only consists of ".;"

Comment: I had to fight quite a while with my installation. Everything was pointing to the right place but I still got the 'Cannot locate java installation'. Then I found out that having the JAVA_HOME without the quotes worked out. Do an echo %JAVA_HOME% and you should get C:\Program Files\jre7 instead of "C:\Program Files\jre7"

Answer (score 1):

Changing the value of JAVA_HOME from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\ worked for me. My Environment: Win XP, added c:\jruby\bin to the PATH var and created JRUBY_HOME pointing to c:\jruby.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I had my JAVA_HOME environment variable missing. fixing that worked for me in Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried everything mentioned here without success.

My solution: reboot your PC. Worked for me!